ZAP and Burpsuit
Why is there a difference in the ZAP and Burp Suit reports even though we run the same report for the same web Application? I was doing the Manual intervention for my website.
I want to know if I can make any configuration changes in ZAP to get the same report as the Burp suit. Are there any configuration changes between the two sites?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please add more details in your question. Two reports are different in what terms? Findings? Format? Timing? Explain in detail what details you found extra or missing compared to both reports, then maybe people can answer your question.

Quick answer - no. ZAP and Burp are different tools developed by different teams. ZAP is not designed to be a Burp clone and so theres no specific "act like Burp Suite" configuration.
Longer answer - yes they are doing similar things. They might be reporting the same things but in slightly different ways. Or one or other tool might be reporting false positives or missing false negatives.
It is imposible to say without a lot more info.
If you do want to provide more info then the ZAP User Group would be a better place to discuss this: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

Hi, I have received a very different report compared to the burp suite run, of the 2 reports that are generated to the same web application that I ran the scan on can you tell me why it is different for both the ZAP and Burp suite report?  I need to get detail information about the reason for the different reports

Please read my above answer again. Theres no way anyone can answer that question without a lot more details.
